# Jquery edit code to select only one checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

**EDIT -**

Thanks for your help on this guys, taking your advise I understand your all correct, I should use a code more suited to my needs and, issue is I cant code one yet so due to deadlines I need to borrow one and I found one suited to my needs with one issue.

Here is the code I want to use.

http://jsfiddle.net/magicalex/FmQvc/

HTML

```
<input data-bedrooms="1" type="checkbox">1 bedroom<br>
<input data-bedrooms="2" type="checkbox">2 bedrooms<br>
<input data-bedrooms="3" type="checkbox">3 bedrooms<br><br>
<ul>
<li data-bedrooms="1">1 bedroom apartment</li>
<li data-bedrooms="1">1 bedroom apartment</li>
<li data-bedrooms="3">3 bedroom apartment</li>
<li data-bedrooms="2">2 bedroom apartment</li>
<li data-bedrooms="2">2 bedroom apartment</li>
<li data-bedrooms="2">2 bedroom apartment</li>
<li data-bedrooms="3">3 bedroom apartment</li>
<li data-bedrooms="2">2 bedroom apartment</li>
<li data-bedrooms="1">1 bedroom apartment</li>
<li data-bedrooms="2">2 bedroom apartment</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
$('input').change(function() {
  var allchecked=0; 
  $('input').each(function() {
    var checked;
    if (checked = $(this).attr('checked')) {allchecked++};
    var numberofrooms = $('li[data-bedrooms='+$(this).data('bedrooms')+']');
    checked ?  numberofrooms.show('slow'): numberofrooms.hide('slow');
  });
  if(allchecked==0){$('li').show('slow');}
});
```

When you start it up it shows all the results to the checkboxes right away then filters them when the user ticks a checkbox for the relevant results then when you un-tick every box the results all show up again. Could anyone tell me how to reverse this, have all the results hidden at startup and hidden again when no checkboxes are ticked?

Thanks,

Comment: If you do not want the automated checking of checkboxes, why make use of that? If I read your question correctly, you want a standard checkbox look and feel?

Comment: @Flater Yes thats Right, This code is perfect for my needs. The issue is if I code in a result that say has 6 different tags which each have a checkbox of their own, if I select one of those checkboxes the code will automatically tick the other 5 checkboxes that correspond to the tags. I would like to remove that function from this code so that the only checkboxes that are ticked are the ones the users select. I have tried other checkbox filters and this is the only one that suits my design needs at the moment and when it comes to Jquery im a novice.

Comment: Why not use checkboxes as they are originally designed to be used? I see no point in using a specific custom feature if that feature is something you specifically don't want.

Comment: The main reason is because this is my first project doing this much specific coding in JS so if I could do a simple edit it would have been easier than coding the Jquery from scratch, it will just take more time before I know how to code it. Thx for your answers Flater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for the default checkbox behaviour. You can use regular checkboxes and apply styles similar to those from that example page. Don't use their javascript code.

Comment: I know your right, but my lack of JS experience is why I wanted to see if I could do a code edit to this code instead of doing it from scratch, from my C++ background I can recognize some of the elements but not all, ill have to study some more to learn to code it. Thx for your answer Floremin

Answer (score 0):

In order to trigger other checkboxes you can bind an event handler to a "mark all" checkboxe and cause it to trigger the filtering checkboxes.

#### Demo

Here's a [demo on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ulasox/2/edit).

### html:

Given the following html:

```
<div class="checkbox-wrapper">
  <input class="checkbox-all" type="checkbox">
  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
  <input class="checkbox-all" type="checkbox">
  ...
</div>
```

### Javascript:

You can use this Javascript to initiate a checkbox that triggers other checkboxes:

```
$(function(){ // Same as $(document).ready(function(){});

  // Cache variables
  var list, $this, checked;

  // Bind event handler for check all checkbox
  $('.checkbox-wrapper').on('click', '.checkbox-all', function(){

    // Get all checkboxes following the clicked "mark all"
    list = $(this).nextUntil('.checkbox-all', '.checkbox');

    // See if the current all checkbox is "chceked"
    checked = $(this).prop('checked');

    list.each(function(){

      $this = $(this);

      // Trigger the click event          
      if ( checked ){
        if ( !$this.prop('checked') )
          $(this).trigger('click');
      } else {
        if ( $this.prop('checked') )
          $(this).trigger('click');
      }

    });

  });

});
```

This would be used alongside your referenced script for toggling elements.